# Adding a build variant and running it on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

When you create a new `iOS` project you have 2 build variants, `Debug` and `Release` (or at least that's what they are called in Android, Build Variant).

Is it possible to create a another build variant? Let's say, "Staging".

Then, how do I run my app on a different build variant, for example how do I run it in release mode on the emulator/development device?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, here's how.

**To add a build configuration**

1. In the menu to the left, select your project.
2. To the right, you'll see "PROJECT" and "TARGETS". Select your project.
3. Go to the Info tab and click '+' under Configurations and choose "Duplicate "Debug"/"Release" configuration" and name it whatever you'd like.

[image]

**To choose which build type to use**

1. Click "NameOfMyProject" next to the device you're building to (upper left of the screen) and choose "Edit scheme".
2. Choose Run -> Build Configuration -> NameOfYourBuildConfiguration.

Hope it helps.